# How to attach style when convert svg to image

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, inline-styles

All:

Right now, I want to draw a svg and style it with external style. Everything goes well until I try to down load it:

```
function chartExporter(svg){
    // svg is a D3 object
    svg.attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
    var svgDOM = svg.node();
    var html = svgDOM.outerHTML;
    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
    imgobj.src = imgsrc;
    imgobj.onload = function(){
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "sample.svg";
        a.href = imgsrc;
        a.click();
    }
}
```

The problem here is: If I use D3 to add inline style or attributes, the svg downloaded seems good, but if I use external css file to include style, those styles can not be applied to svg when converted( it make sense, cos they are not in that html string), **I wonder how to bring those style into svg?**

Thanks

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, that is why I ask this question that how to bring those external style into one single file( if this is the only way)

Comment: Convert the style to an internal data url.

Comment: @RobertLongson Could you show me how to do that, I am pretty new to that

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: @RobertLongson I thought I already done that: var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I meant the stylesheet, since that's what this question seems to be about.

Comment: @RobertLongson I finally find some solution for this, not understand why but work, http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/

Comment: Step 1 in that code converts stylesheets to data URIs.